# Navigation Drawer not showing when setting contentview in fragment

Tags: android, design-patterns, layout, android-fragments, drawerlayout

My problem:
I have a fragment class with a very complicated layout.
And for my program i am making use of the navigation drawer menu.
For this class i need to do this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planboard, container, false);  // is returned later
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.planboard);
```

If i don't do `setcontentView`, i get some `nullpointers` later on when i try to manipulate the layout elements (but then the nav drawer works).

I would like to get both working simultaneously.

Is there any way to fix this?

I hope that I described the problem good enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show relevant portion of your activity class

Comment: you are inflating R.layout.planboard in fragment and setContentView R.layout.planboard in activiy is taht necessary?

Comment: can you please post your OnCreateView method of Fragment? I presume the problem with NPEs is somehow connected with it

Comment: @Illigal Argument im setting both in the Fragment. There is no relevant code in the activity (only loading of the fragment which is done like:



        fragment = new planboard();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_detail, fragment).commit();

Comment: @Chaosit, my onCreateView from the relevant fragment: http://pastie.org/9428889

Comment: The activity layout should just have a "container" that you are adding the fragments to. Your fragment should inflate the complex layout.

Comment: @willie Nel  -  I have that its called "Fragment_detail"

 
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffbaeeff" >

Comment: Okay that's fine. Just make sure you are using setContentView() in the onCreate method of your activity before you add your fragment. The getActivity().setContentView() call should not be in your fragment onCreateView().